# How to find the second derivative of an implicit function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

We know from multivariable calculus that if $y(x)$ is a function given implicitly by the equation $F(x,y) = 0$, then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{F_x}{F_y} \tag{1}
$$
This is quickly proved by applying the multivariable chain rule to $\frac{d}{dx}F(x,y(x))=0$.

There is also a formula for the second derivative of $y$, but it is more complicated:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = -\frac{F_{xx}F^2_y - 2F_{xy}F_xF_y+F_{yy}F^2_x}{F^3_y} \tag{2}$$
How is the formula (2) derived?

Comment: You may think it's easier for us to take the time figure out what that mess of an equation says than for you to take the time to learn how to use the equation editor, but you'd be wrong. ;)

Comment: @User 87398:  I reformatted your math with Latex.  Hope you don't mind.  Hope I got the math right.  By the way, you can actually *see* the Latex here, and in any post, by hovering over an equation and right clicking; then go to "show math as > Tex commands"; a great way to learn Latex!

Comment: How do you obtain dy/dx ? If you know it, you should ba able to continue in a similar way.

Comment: I attempted to bring the question into shape. Hope it can be reopened, since this is a pretty standard calculus formula.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's pretty clear, despite the question in Tanner Swett's comment, that $F(x, y)$ is a sufficiently smooth function of the two variables $x$ and $y$ that the equation $F(x, y) = 0$ defines $y(x)$ as an implicit function of $x$; that is, $F(x, y(x)) = 0$.  Of course lurking behind such a definition of $y(x)$ is the implicit function theorem and the hypothesis that $F_y \ne 0$.  Under such circumstances we have, for $F(x, y) = c$, $c$ a constant, that

$F_x + F_y y'(x) = dF(x, y(x)) / dx = 0, \tag{1}$

so that

$y'(x) = -F_x / F_y; \tag{2}$

then

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y''(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(-F_x / F_y) = -\frac{d}{dx}(F_x / F_y).  \tag{3}$

We compute, using the standard formula for $(f/g)'$, $(f/g)' = (f'g - fg') / f^2$, and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}G(x, y(x)) = G_x + G_yy'$ for any sufficiently differentiable function of two variables $G(x, y)$:

$-\frac{d}{dx}(F_x / F_y) = -((F_{xx} + F_{xy}y')F_y - F_x(F_{yx} + F_{yy}y'))/F^2_y, \tag{4}$

and into this we substitute $-F_x / F_y$ for $y'$, and then grind by diligently turning the drive crank of the algebra machine:

$((F_{xx} + F_{xy}y')F_y - F_x(F_{yx} + F_{yy}y'))/F^2_y$
$ = ((F_{xx} + F_{xy}(-F_x / F_y))F_y - F_x(F_{yx} + F_{yy}(-F_x / F_y)))/F^2_y$
$=(F_{xx}F_y - F_{xy}F_x - F_{yx}F_x + F_{yy}F_x^2/F_y)/F^2_y. \tag{5}$

Now use the "sufficiently differentiable" clause to conclude $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$ and then simply multiply the numerator and denominator by $F_y$, and turn the crank on that mill just one more time; the refined product is

$y''(x) = -\frac{d}{dx}(F_x / F_y) = -(F_{xx}F_y^2 - 2F_{xy}F_xF_y+ F_{yy}F_x^2)/F^3_y, \tag{6}$

as per request.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: wow, thank you very much, I have no idea about this problem. I just received it from my friend who felt difficulty to solve the question.