# A function of class $C^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

**Problem:** given a function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$, with $F(0,0)=0,\nabla F=(2,3)$, shown that a surface $F(x+2y+3z-1,x^3+y^2-z^2)=0$ can be given locally at $(-2,3,-1)$ as graph of $z\stackrel{c^2}{=}z(x,y)$.
then compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(-2,3)}$, and knowing that $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=3$,$\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=-1$ and $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial y^2}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=5$, compute $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(-2,3)}$

I dont known of how to solve this, i think that will need something like chain rule.

Comment: You need [implicit function theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/530573/).

Comment: Are you sure it's $x^3 +y^2 -z^2$?

Comment: @jeremy I received this question from my friend, and the data of the question that i received are these, then i can't say exact if they are correct or no.

Comment: I asked cause, if $F(0,0)=0$ and $F=(x+2y+3z-1,x^3+y^2-z^2)=0$ then $x+2y+3z-1=0$ and $x^3+y^2-z^2=0$. So, maybe you can imagine like the intersection of both surface, which in the case that would be $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ is a cone (the other surface is a plane)